# Android MediaPlayer Starts sound but doesn't start up again

Tags: android, media-player

I made a basic app with 2 buttons, start and stop. When I start the app and hit the start button the sound starts, and when I the end button it stops, BUT if I try to start up again with the start button it doesn't start again.

Code:

```
    buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonStart);
    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickButton(buttonStart);
        }
    });
    buttonEnd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonEnd);
    buttonEnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickButton(buttonEnd);
        }
    });
    beat = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beat);

    public void onClickButton(Button button){
        if(button == buttonStart){
            beat.start();
            beat.setLooping(true);
        }
        else if(button == buttonEnd){
            beat.stop();
            //beat.setLooping(false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you stop the media player then the instance of the media player is destroyed so if you want to play again. Then you have to create the instance of media player again. Put this code in your buttonStart

```
beat = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beat);
beat.start();
beat.setLooping(true);
```

Best of luck and don't forget to tick that this answer is useful to you.